# Can I wake up an iOS app on low battery? How?

Tags: ios, iphone, batterylevel, wakeup

We are a software development company and have a number of phones that we use for testing this or that web site. The need to test something exactly on a live small iPhones (e.g. iPhone 5S) happens not very often and, oups, the device wasn't charged for too long and I cannot run a test right away.

I want to create a small monitoring utility that would beep and/or send email and/or elsehow ping me when the phone's battery is low and device needs to be charged. Certainly monitoring should work even when app is not running as we will definitely forget about the need to keep it running all the time.

Is waking up an app possible on iOS? Which APIs to look at?

Comment: Why not just leave the chargers plugged in ?

Comment: See [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification).

Comment: @PaulR, it must be cheaper to develop a software solution than to buy enough charging cables to keep them plugged in. :D

Comment: @NRitH: it depends on how much your time is worth - if a programmer costs $50/hour and spends two days writing such a utility then that's $800, which would buy quite a few chargers.

Comment: We don't have many power sockets available and move phones around as well. I'd like to be notified if a phone is in my backpack as well.

The app would be a half-hobby project certainly :)

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/news/capacious-juice-packs-to-consider-before-your-next-trip/

Answer (score 1):

Usually the app has to be running to be able to get any sort of notifications such as this. [This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4) shows what types of activities are allowed in the background, and you probably won't be able to get UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification background notifications, just when the app is actually open. Might just be worth buying a few charging cables!